# How to use Toast from blueprintjs with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I get trouble to use Toast from blueprintjs
I succeed to display it, but when I click on the cross the toast doesn't close and the timeout doesn't work.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<Toaster position={Position.TOP}>
      <Toast message="Votre message a bien été envoyé." className="text-lime-800" timeout={3000}/>
 </Toaster>
```

The documentation explains that I have to link my toaster with a Reference, but I don't understand why :/
I tried to create one like this:

```
const toaster = useRef(null);
...
<Toaster position={Position.TOP} ref={toaster}>
      <Toast message="Votre message a bien été envoyé." className="text-lime-800" timeout={3000}/>
 </Toaster>
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Could you help me pls ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `<Toaster><Toast>...</Toast></Toaster>` API to render toast components directly, then you are responsible for maintaining state for the currently displayed list of toasts. `<Toaster>` will not *automatically* hide its children Toasts for you; you will have to remove them from the React tree. This is demonstrated in the ["React component usage" documentation section](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/toast.react-component-usage).

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution.

First, create your ref using useRef

```
const toaster = useRef(null);
```

Then, connect into your Toast component:

```
<Toaster ref={toaster} />
```

Later, you have to do a trick before show a new toast. When you should call `show` normally, do this:

```
if (!!toaster && !!toaster.current) {
  const toasterInstance = toaster.current as ToasterInstance;
  toasterInstance.show({
    ...
  });
}
```

That worked for me, I hope it can help you.